# Using AutoFill in Excel VBA for a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a code, that will find the last row in an excel spread sheet, and autofill 24 more rows with same formulas that the last two rows contain (like you do the autofill manually). Column A contains date and time with one hour period like this:

```
26/5/15 00:00
26/5/15 01:00 
and so on...
```

Columns B-G contain formulas that are applied according to the time in appropriate cell in column A

This is the code I came up with:

```
Sub FillDay()
Dim Initial_cell, Var_1, Final_End_Row As Long, Update_range, Range_To_Fill As String
Dim col, n, b As Integer, rng As Range
col = 1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(col)) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You have selected a blank column"
n = 0
Else
Set rng = Intersect(Columns(col), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
On Error Resume Next
b = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
n = rng.Cells.Count - b
On Error GoTo 0
n = n + 1
End If
'n returns the number of the last occupied cell
Initial_cell = n
Var_1 = Initial_cell - 2
Update_range = "A" & Var_1 & ":" & "G" & Initial_cell
Final_End_Row = Initial_cell + 24
Range_To_Fill = "A" & Initial_cell & ":" & "G" & Final_End_Row
Range(Update_range).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range_To_Fill), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Getting Run-time error '1004' Application defined or object defined error...
Using the debug the problem seems to be in the last line

New to VBA, any help is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: On which line do you have the error?

Comment: It seems to be the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the last bit of your code to

```
Initial_cell = n - 1
Var_1 = Initial_cell - 2
Update_range = "A" & Var_1 & ":" & "G" & Initial_cell
Final_End_Row = Initial_cell + 24
Range_To_Fill = "A" & Var_1 & ":" & "G" & Final_End_Row
Range(Update_range).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range_To_Fill), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

2 problems:-
1 you included a blank row in Initial_cell (this may be intentional?). 
2 the autofill destination needs to start on the same row that update_range does

another thing to think about might be that var_1=initial_setup -2 could cause an error later down the line if it is negative

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was with the destination, as you mentioned Update_range and Range_To_Fill need to start from the same row. Can't figure out where the blank row comes from in Initial_cell, though. Can you explain this moment please.
Initial cell will be allways greater than 2, so there will be no problem of negative value of Var_1.

Comment: If you go into the first if statement:- n is set to 0, then Initial_cell will be set to 0 and you will have -2 in Var_1. you may want to move the last 6 lines of code under the "else" part of your if statement